# Div layout not getting same results as expected

Tags: html, css

I am cleaning up a decade old website and turning it into divs (much cleaner). Sill learning, of course. Thanks to S.O. and ducking around, I've learned a lot over the years. Getting rid of tables (not that they are bad.. just looks cleaner this way)

All I am trying to do is align two divs horizontal. But according to what I've learned, is that floating them left (or right) each, SHOULD put them on the same line side by side. However, this does not work for me. I tried block method, but nothing. Below I am trying to get the "action" div on the left, and on the right the "specs" on the right. So I think I have it right, but something in interfering, so maybe a second pair of eyes?

The other part, which I think is related, no matter what I put in the ".action_msg" for the width - it does not change which is very annoying as it is aesthetically UNpleasing.
Obviously this is all easy with tables, but it is too noisy that way, and a lot of unnecessary coding, so I decided to clean all this up with divs

[image: bad layout]

Desired result - to be able to stretch price (or free sample) so they ar same size, and specs like to see on the right (horizontal to the action div) and safty message where it is at.

DISCLAIMER: There were some similar questions (9 of them) on S.O. by others, but none have been answered or viewed.So what they miss is lots of code example which I put here.

```css
    #action_wrapper     { width: 300px; float: right;}
    .action_msg         { width: 250px;  border: 1px solid yellow; padding:5px; border-radius: 5px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;}
    .action             { float:right; background-color: blue; color: white; border: 2px cyan solid; border-radius: 5px; width: 150px; padding:5px; display: inline-block;}
    .safty_msg          { padding: 20px;}
    #spec_wrapper       { float: left; }
```

```html
    <div id="action_wrapper">
            <p >
                
                <span class="action_msg">Free Sample</span>
                <span class="action"><a href="download/{gameid}">Download</a></span>
            </p>
            
            <p>
                 <span class="action_msg">{price}</span>
                 <span class="action"><a href="addtocart/{gameid}">Add to your cart</a> </span>            
            </p>         
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        
        <div class="safty_msg">Safe & Secure Downloads Quality Tested & Virus Free</div>
        
        <div id="spec_wrapper">
            <div id="specs">
                <ul>
                    <li>OS: {pc_sysreqos}</li>
                    <li>Game Size {gamesize},</li>
                    <li>CPU: {pc_sysreqmhz}</li>
                    <li>RAM: {pc_sysreqmem}</li>                
                    <li>Hard Drive: {pc_sysrechdd}</li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

modified using flex (right track anyone?)

html

```
<div class="action_container">

            <div class="download">
                <p class="action_msg">Free Sample</p>
                <p class="action_msg">{price}</p>

            </div>
            <div class="buy">
                <p class="action"><a href="download/{gameid}">Download</a></p> 
                <p class="action"><a href="addtocart/{gameid}">Add to your cart</a> </p>            
            </div>

            <div id="specs">
                <ul>
                    <li>OS: {pc_sysreqos}</li>
                    <li>Game Size {gamesize},</li>
                    <li>CPU: {pc_sysreqmhz}</li>
                    <li>RAM: {pc_sysreqmem}</li>                
                    <li>Hard Drive: {pc_sysrechdd}</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.action_container   { display: flex; width: 550px; justify-content: space-between;}
.download           { flex:1;}
.buy                { flex:2;}
.action_msg         { border: 2px solid yellow; border-radius: 5px; padding:5px; width:120px;}
.action             { background-color: blue; color: white; border: 2px cyan solid; border-radius: 5px; padding:5px; }
.safty_msg          { padding: 20px; width: 100%; text-align: center;}
```

[image]

Comment: something is overwriting the style for one of action tags, you could have more div tags replace the paragraph tags for your styles to give yourself more flexibility. What does chrome's style debugger say about the styles?

Comment: good point, but the spec wrapper is outside of the action wrapper, and that is the wrapper(spec) I want on the right, theoretically it should not be interfered by anything.. just two divs "action"-left and "specs" - right, but your right, something is preventing it..

Answer (score 2):

you should not use tags like that , try this wrap those 4 thing in separate p tags and use display flex  for example

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .parent{
         display:flex;
         justify-content:space-between;
         align-items :center
         }
         .parent p{
         display:block
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="parent">
         <p>free sample</p>
         <p>Downloads</p>
         <p>usd</p>
         <p>Add crat</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

use nth child selectors to style different

tags inside

Comment: lol, now I gotta learn two more terms "flex" and "space-between" (Im old school div catching up). Currently what I just did a min ago, was remove the clear:both, that put the specs where I wanted, but the safty_msg wrapped, but thats an easy fix. Your solution looks cleaner yet. let me redo that with yours and see what I come up with. I will post a functional final shortly.

Comment: Indeed - using floats for the layout you are after is an "old school" approach - flex or grid or even just display: inline-block would be better now :)

Comment: @Faizal Hussain Ok I did some research on flex . Then I tried yours. It does work, but it is all one row. I need two rows. And switchin from span to p, made a huge diff, but not the direction I want to go. #cale_b, Yes, I learned html, JS back in early 90's - I was stubborn with the <br/> <-- note the slash vs the <br> I used to use LOL. And CSS I wasn't even going there. But age = wisdom. I am going to check with the grid too. The old game template was heavily tabled, and I see with divs, it can clean up a lot. Im still hackin away.. when I get it (w/o tables) I'll post the result for others

Comment: i DID AN edit with FLEX, bumpy for first time - if I am on the right track.. I can pursue it from here - but ya, easier to manipulate and edit. Check the OP for new edit addition

Comment: if you want to break the row , give a width to the parent ,and use flex wrap: wrap which will break the contents